# Copy file name and create new blank file with it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of .bak files in a directory.

Now I want to duplicate/copy those files to another directory, but only keep the filename, not the content - How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cmd prompt command - double the `%` to `%%` to use it in a batch file.

```
for %a in ("d:\folder\*.bak") do type nul>"c:\newfolder\%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
robocopy c:\source c:\target *.bak /create
```

For a pre windows Vista solution you can use

```
for %f in ("c:\source\*.bak") do break > "c:\target\%~nxf"
```

If it should be used from a batch file, change `%` with `%%`

Comment: This only works from Windows Vista/Server 2008 onwards, where `robocopy` is included by default. Otherwise it's part of the Windows Resource Kit and needs to be installed manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`for /R C:\Backup %%f in (*.bak) do type NUL > "C:\New\%%~nxf"`

Comment: Add some double quotes to support long filenames too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Julian. Problem is that on my Windows Server 2008 R2 standard, the script cannot parse/execute the ~ character - It keeps saying ECHO is off (or on) when looking at the output, even if I enable delayedexpansions...Hence, since I user Windows 2008 R2, MC ND's solution will work best for my scenario

Comment: You're saying basic for loop syntax, which has been around since before Windows XP, doesn't work in Windows Server 2008? I doubt it.